# JQGrid: Pass JQGrid column value as a parameter to controller method specified in cellurl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am looking for inline editing a JQGrid.

My JQGrid having column like :

```
    colModel: [
               { name: 'Model_ID', index: 'model_id', width: 100, editable: false, hidden:  
                false },
               { name: 'Cust_Nm', index: 'cust_nm', width: 100, editable: false},
               { name: 'Model_Nm', index: 'model_nm', width: 140, editable: false, },
               { name: 'Client_Nm1', index: 'client_nm1', width: 120, editable: true},
               { name: 'Client_Nm2', index: 'client_nm2', width: 120, editable: true},
               { name: 'Client_Nm3', index: 'client_nm3', width: 120, editable: true},
               { name: 'Date', index: 'regi_date', width: 130, editable:false, search: false }
              ],
            cellEdit: true,
            cellurl: '@Url.Action("UpdateJQGrid", "Config")',
            cellsubmit: "remote"
```

I want to pass value of 'Model_ID' to "UpdateJQGrid" Controller method. UpdateJQGrid is getting called when I edit one cell and move the focus to other cell inside the jggrid. I have created a View Model and passing that ViewModel to the Controller Method. But I am getting only the edited value through ViewModel object not other values of the selected row. If I can get only the value of Model_ID in Controller method my requirement will be solved.
Any help or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: I think that the origin of your problem already exist in *filling* of the grid. So, some questions: Contains `Model_ID` (or `model_id`) column **unique** value in every row of the grid? Is `Model_ID` (or `model_id`) the native `id` from some table of the database? Which format of data you use to fill the grid (could you provide an example with one or two rows of test data)? Why you use different values for `name` and `index` properties in `colModel`?

Comment: @Oleg Model_ID column is unique... JQGrid data will populate from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important to understand that the implementation of jqGrid **require** to assign `id` attribute to every row of the grid (to every `<tr>` element of the `<table>` with the main data). The documentation use `rowid` as the value of `id` attribute. If you use editing feature of jqGrid it's strictly recommended that you assign the value of `id` attribute based on the *native* value which will be get from the database (existing on the backend side). The `rowid` will be used in the most callbacks of jqGrid and will be post to the server during editing. [Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server) you can read which information will be send to the server during cell editing.

If the values from `Model_ID` (or `model_id`) column are **unique** and the values come from the database than I would recommend you to use the value as the `rowid`. To inform jqGrid to use the value you can either specify the corresponding value of `id` property of `jsonReader` (or `xmlReader`). The value of `id` property depends on the exact format of the data returned from the server, which you use to fill the grid. Another way will be to specify `key: true` property in `Model_ID` (`model_id`) column. After the changes you will see that jqGrid will send the value from `Model_ID` (`model_id`) column to the server during cell editing. The value will be send as `id=rowid` (as `id` parameter). You can change the name of the parameter by usage `prmNames: {id: "Model_ID"}`, for example, which changes `id=rowid` to `Model_ID=rowid`.

One more remark. I recommend you don't use `index` property if it is not *really required*. If you miss the property then the value of `name` property will be used instead. The usage of *different* values for `name` and `index` properties is the origin of many errors and makes impossible to use *client side* sorting, paging and filtering/searching.

Comment: Awesome @Oleg.... Working like a charm... Thanks a lot... I was Fighting for it almost for a day.... :)